# Spree test rspec Failure/Error: expecting <"new"> but rendering with <[]>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, spree

I've been trying to pass this test suite on our spree app but it keeps saying:

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template(:new)
       expecting <"new"> but rendering with <[]>
```

Here's the test:

```
context 'New action' do
    it 'render view new template' do
      spree_get :new
      expect(response).to render_template(:new)
    end
  end
```

What's weird is when I test this code it passes, they're basically the same:

```
context 'Index action' do
    it 'render view index template' do
      spree_get :index
      expect(response).to render_template(:index)
    end
    
    it 'index should have a status code of 200', focus: true do
      spree_get :index
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end
  end
```

also tried adding `render_views` doesn't work. I also followed the instruction on this link [spree_test](https://blog.rebased.pl/2015/01/03/a-primer-to-testing-spree-applications.html) still no luck. I also run it many times without touching the code hoping that it will work nothing happens.

**Additional Information**

```
spec/support/spree_controller_request.rb

require 'spree/testing_support/controller_requests'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Spree::TestingSupport::ControllerRequests, :type => :controller
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

```
spec/spec_helper.rb

# This file was generated by the `rails generate rspec:install` command. Conventionally, all
# specs live under a `spec` directory, which RSpec adds to the `$LOAD_PATH`.
# The generated `.rspec` file contains `--require spec_helper` which will cause
# this file to always be loaded, without a need to explicitly require it in any
# files.
#
# Given that it is always loaded, you are encouraged to keep this file as
# light-weight as possible. Requiring heavyweight dependencies from this file
# will add to the boot time of your test suite on EVERY test run, even for an
# individual file that may not need all of that loaded. Instead, consider making
# a separate helper file that requires the additional dependencies and performs
# the additional setup, and require it from the spec files that actually need
# it.

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'
#
# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration
require 'capybara/rspec'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    # This option will default to `true` in RSpec 4. It makes the `description`
    # and `failure_message` of custom matchers include text for helper methods
    # defined using `chain`, e.g.:
    #     be_bigger_than(2).and_smaller_than(4).description
    #     # => "be bigger than 2 and smaller than 4"
    # ...rather than:
    #     # => "be bigger than 2"
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended, and will default to
    # `true` in RSpec 4.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  # This option will default to `:apply_to_host_groups` in RSpec 4 (and will
  # have no way to turn it off -- the option exists only for backwards
  # compatibility in RSpec 3). It causes shared context metadata to be
  # inherited by the metadata hash of host groups and examples, rather than
  # triggering implicit auto-inclusion in groups with matching metadata.
  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups

  # The settings below are suggested to provide a good initial experience
  # with RSpec, but feel free to customize to your heart's content.
  begin
    # This allows you to limit a spec run to individual examples or groups
    # you care about by tagging them with `:focus` metadata. When nothing
    # is tagged with `:focus`, all examples get run. RSpec also provides
    # aliases for `it`, `describe`, and `context` that include `:focus`
    # metadata: `fit`, `fdescribe` and `fcontext`, respectively.
    # config.filter_run_when_matching :focus

    # Allows RSpec to persist some state between runs in order to support
    # the `--only-failures` and `--next-failure` CLI options. We recommend
    # you configure your source control system to ignore this file.
    # config.example_status_persistence_file_path = "spec/examples.txt"

    # Limits the available syntax to the non-monkey patched syntax that is
    # recommended. For more details, see:
    #   - http://rspec.info/blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax/
    #   - http://www.teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
    #   - http://rspec.info/blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3/#zero-monkey-patching-mode
    config.disable_monkey_patching!

    # Many RSpec users commonly either run the entire suite or an individual
    # file, and it's useful to allow more verbose output when running an
    # individual spec file.
    # if config.files_to_run.one?
      # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
      # unless a formatter has already been configured
      # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
      # config.default_formatter = "doc"
    # end

    # Print the 10 slowest examples and example groups at the
    # end of the spec run, to help surface which specs are running
    # particularly slow.
    # config.profile_examples = 10

    # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
    # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
    # the seed, which is printed after each run.
    #     --seed 1234
    config.order = :random

    # Seed global randomization in this process using the `--seed` CLI option.
    # Setting this allows you to use `--seed` to deterministically reproduce
    # test failures related to randomization by passing the same `--seed` value
    # as the one that triggered the failure.
    Kernel.srand config.seed
  end
end
```

```
spec/rails_helper.rb

# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rails'
# require 'capybara/rspec'
# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
# spec/support/ and its subdirectories. Files matching `spec/**/*_spec.rb` are
# run as spec files by default. This means that files in spec/support that end
# in _spec.rb will both be required and run as specs, causing the specs to be
# run twice. It is recommended that you do not name files matching this glob to
# end with _spec.rb. You can configure this pattern with the --pattern
# option on the command line or in ~/.rspec, .rspec or `.rspec-local`.
#
# The following line is provided for convenience purposes. It has the downside
# of increasing the boot-up time by auto-requiring all files in the support
# directory. Alternatively, in the individual `*_spec.rb` files, manually
# require only the support files necessary.
#
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec', 'support', '**', '*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations and applies them before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove these lines.
begin
  ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
rescue ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError => e
  puts e.to_s.strip
  exit 1
end
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # FactoryBot
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods

  # Database Cleaner
  # source: http://www.virtuouscode.com/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/
  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.before(:suite) do
    # RAILS_ENV and Rails.env can be different at times; fail if any of the two is different
    abort("The Rails environment is not running in test mode!") if !Rails.env.test? || ENV['RAILS_ENV'] != 'test'
    
    # Prevent database truncation if the environment is not test
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end
  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end
  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
  # when testing methods with transactions, we have to manage commits / rollbacks manually (ex: option_type_generator_spec.rb):
  # 1. Add testing_transactions: true to the example call
  #    - this tells database_cleaner to NOT wrap the example in a transaction (we'll manage the test and cleanup ourselves)
  # 2. Wrap the test logic inside a transaction
  #    - make sure that the transaction to be tested allows for nested transactions (requires_new: true)
  # 3. Execute the test sequence and the necessary tests
  # 4. Afterwards, ensure cleanup:
  #    - rollback the test transaction
  #    - after rollback, inspect the data to make sure that test details did not persist
  config.around(:each, :testing_transactions => true) do |ex|
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = nil
    ex.run
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
  # config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")
end

# Shoulda 
require 'shoulda/matchers'
Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you restart you test environnement? Go out of your test, type `spring stop` and re-run your specs

Comment: @morissetcl same thing. this is frustrating. spree should have some documentation on how to set up test environments. :(

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you put your new spec in your `index` test?

Comment: @morissetcl nope. index is fine. giving me the right template.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Can you put `spree_get :new
 expect(response).to render_template(:new) ` within your index spec files. Just to check if it's works.

Comment: there in the same file actually. I was thinking maybe its the authorization because when I try to `redirect` gives me a `/login.com` but I don't know where to start fixing it because spree doesn't provide detailed documentation. If I can fix this maybe I could try to make a PR.